# Concurrent hash table in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

In my application I basically have multiple threads that perform inserts and mostly one thread that is iterating through a map and removing items if it meets certain criteria. The reason I wanted to use a concurrent structure is that it would have provided finer grain locking in the code that removes items from the queue which looks similar to this which is not ideal for various reasons including that the thread could get pre-empted while holding the lock.

```
Function_reap()
{
   while(timetaken != timeoutTime)
   {
      my_map_mutex.lock();

      auto iter = my_unordered_map.begin();
      while(iter != my_unordered_map.end())
      {
        if(status_completed == iter->second.status)
        {
          iter = my_unordered_map.erase(iter);
        }
      }

      my_map_mutex.unlock();
   }
}
```

Was going through the documentation for Intel TBB(Threading Building Blocks) and more specifically the concurrent_unordered_map documentation (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506171) to see if this is a good fit for my application and came across this excerpt.

> > **Description** concurrent_unordered_map and concurrent_unordered_multimap support concurrent insertion and
> >     traversal, but not concurrent erasure. The interfaces have no visible
> >     locking. They may hold locks internally, but never while calling
> >     user-defined code. They have semantics similar to std::unordered_map
> >     and std::unordered_multimap respectively, except as follows:
>
> - The erase and extract methods are prefixed with unsafe_, to indicate that they are not concurrency safe.

- Why does TBB not provide safe synchronized deletion from the map? what is the technical reason for this?
- What if any other options do i have here? Ideally something that definitely works on Linux and if possible portable to windows.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is difficult to design a solution that (efficiently) supports *all* operations. TBB has the [`concurrent_unordered_map`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506171) which supports concurrent insert, find and iteration, but no erase - and the [`concurrent_hash_map`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506191) which supports concurrent insert, find and erase, but no iteration.

There are several other libraries that provide concurrent hash maps like libcds, or my own one called [xenium](https://github.com/mpoeter/xenium).

ATM xenium contains two concurrent hash map implementations:

- `harris_michael_hash_map` - fully lock-free; supports concurrent insert, erase, find and iteration. However, the number of buckets has to be defined at construction time and cannot be adapted afterwards. Each bucket contains a linked list of items, which is not very cache friendly.
- `vyukov_hash_map` - is a very fast hash map that uses fine grained locking for insert, erase and iteration; find operations are lock-free. However, if are using iterators you have to be careful to avoid deadlocks (i.e., a thread should not try to insert or erase a key while holding an iterator). However, there is an erase overload that takes an iteration, so you can safely remove the item the iterator points to.

I am currently working to make xenium fully windows compatible.

Comment: Thanks, for the pointer, appreciate. Will look both of these up and give them a try.

Comment: Follow up question on the vyukon_hash_map. The deadlock scenario you mentioned, makes sense at a general level - does this deadlock scenario also hold for erase\removing from map? I am hoping not and in case it does not would love to hear your explanation as to why the insert deadlocks but not the erase if performed on the same thread that is iterating.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the deadlock scenario also holds for other operations that modify the hash map and therefore have to acquire a bucket lock (i.e., emplace, erase, extract). However, there is an erase overload that takes an iterator, so you can safely remove the item the iterator points to.

Comment: I have edited my original answer to communicate this clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and that is good to hear that there is an overload that supports this. I thought about this a little more on a more general level... can this deadlock scenario go away by using something like a recursive mutex?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not that simple. The lock is a kind of spinlock on an internal state field that contains additional data to make the lookup operation lock-free, But even if I would use some reentrant lock for the buckets, you could still run in a deadlock with a concurrent insert operation that has to grow/rehash the table.
BTW: yesterday I found an issue in the erase function that takes an iterator, that can cause the bucket to be unlocked prematurely. I will push a fix for that in the coming days.

Comment: FYI: I just pushed said fix!